# Specflow : Test scenario is not getting displayed in test explorer

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow

When i add test scenario in feature file it is not getting displayed after build. in VS 2015.

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow are you using? Which NuGet packages do you have installed? Which unit test provider are you using? I'm sorry, but we need more information to answer your question.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Do you have the SpecFlow extension installed, and which version do you have?

Comment: SpecFlow version 2.4.1                                                                                                                          Newtonsoft.Json version 11.0.2

Comment: Please add this to your question. It is too easy for this information to get lost in the comments.

Comment: Also, which version of the SpecFlow plugin for Visual Studio do you have? Which version of Visual studio?

Comment: Studio version 14.0.25431.01

Comment: Which version of the **SpecFlow plugin for Visual Studio** do you have? And please edit your question with this information, including the updates you made in previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . And when I upgraded my specflow to 3.0.213 , feature.cs and tests were not generated. Then I used [this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/MSBuild/OldCSProj_SpecFlow30)  MSBUild example with latest specflow to generate feature.cs and tests in test explorer. It uses MSTest as test runner.